# Unable to connect to MSSQL Server from Python on Windows

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

I'm unable to connect to SQL Server from Python (3.4.4 64 bit) on Windows 10. This is what I did:

1. I found [this](https://www.pymssql.org/) nice library.
2. Then, I followed [this](https://www.pymssql.org/en/v2.1.2/freetds.html) page and installed *FreeTDS*
3. After that I installed *pymssql* with this command: `easy_install pymssql`
4. In SQL Server Network Configuration I enabled Named Pipes and TCP/IP for my SQLEXPRESS instance

So, at this moment I can run SQL Server and connect to my database, using SQL Server Management Studio. When I log in, I use `DESKTOP-1JA5E9F\SQLEXPRESS` as Server Name, `sa` as Login and `123` as Password. Besides, in Python shell I can import `pymssql` like:

```
>>> import pymssql
```

It does not raise any error. However, I can not connect to my database instance. I tried dozens attempts like:

```
 conn = pymssql.connect(host=r'DESKTOP-1JA5E9F\SQLEXPRESS', 
                        user=r'sa', password=r'123', database=r'reestr')
```

The code above ^^^ never completes (I see just blinking `_` in the shell, that is blinking for ever). I also tried this:

```
conn = pymssql.connect(host=r'SQLEXPRESS', user=r'sa', password=r'123', database=r'reestr')
```

This results in `pymssql.InterfaceError: Connection to the database failed for an unknown reason.`. I tried this:

```
conn=pymssql.connect(host=r'SQLEXPRESS:1433',user=r'sa',password=r'123', database=r'reestr')
```

It also results in the same error message. So, I if anybody knows those magic voodoo spells that can do the trick, you are welcome.

Comment: Do you have a `freetds.conf` file? http://pymssql.org/en/v2.1.2/freetds.html#configuration

Comment: Yes, I have it in C:\ folder with exactly the same contents.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165031/connect-to-sql-server-instance-using-pymssql-on-windows According to this user the 'SQL Server Browser' service must be running on the SQL server's host.

Comment: For some reason, it is impossible to enable it. I can only enable SQL Server and SQL Server VSS Writer

Comment: In configuration manager Start, Pause and other command are disabled for some reason for SQL Server Browser.

Comment: Oh, I managed to start it.

Comment: Well, I checked it. Even though SQL Server Browser is running, I still can not connect from Python to my database. So, I guess there are some other secrets to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acording to the [docs](http://pymssql.org/en/latest/ref/pymssql.html), there's no `host` keyword arg anymore, but `server`. Also it should be server name, not instance name, or full instance name (with server name). See [`connect()` description](http://pymssql.org/en/latest/ref/pymssql.html#functions) , and [examples of name construction for `Connection` class](http://pymssql.org/en/latest/ref/pymssql.html#connection-class).

In your case server name is `DESKTOP-1JA5E9F`, also `.` and `(local)` should work since you do it all on local machine; your named instance name is `SQLEXPRESS`.

Try like these:

```
import pymssql

#for instance with known name 'SQLEXPRESS'
conn = pymssql.connect(server=r'DESKTOP-1JA5E9F\SQLEXPRESS', 
                       user=r'sa', password=r'123', database=r'reestr')
#on localhost this should work too
conn = pymssql.connect(server=r'.\SQLEXPRESS', 
                       user=r'sa', password=r'123', database=r'reestr')

#for default instance with port taken from freetds.conf
#(this probably won't work for your case, because you use named instance
#instead of default instance, which is named MSSQLSERVER)
conn = pymssql.connect(server=r'DESKTOP-1JA5E9F', user=r'sa', password=r'123',    
                       database=r'reestr')

#for instance on known port '1433'
conn = pymssql.connect(server=r'DESKTOP-1JA5E9F:1433', user=r'sa', password=r'123',
                       database=r'reestr')
```

If this won't help, test the connection with `tsql` as [described in the docs](http://pymssql.org/en/latest/freetds.html#testing-the-connection), e.g.:

```
tsql -H DESKTOP-1JA5E9F -p 1433 -U sa -P 123 -D reestr
```

or if you have `freetds.conf`:

```
tsql -S 'DESKTOP-1JA5E9F\SQLEXPRESS' -U sa -P 123 -D reestr
```

Comment: Thank you, Nikita! I will check it today. As for `tsql`, on my Windows machine this command does not work, even though I installed freetds following the instruction. If you can provide a little more information about tsql and the way to use it on Windows, it would be great.

Comment: @Jacobian, looks like `tslq` is not on system `PATH`, as there's a mention in the docs, that you might want to add some folders from your installation to the `PATH` manually. But you can run it directly from the command line without modifying the `PATH` variable, just use full path scpecification. `tsql` should be somewhere in the FreeTDS installation directory, [probably in `src/apps`](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/serverthere.htm#SERVERTHERE.TSQL). Just use Windows search, to find `tsql`.

Comment: Well, I tried first two and the last one example from your answer, but what I get is just infinite blinking of `_` in the console. I do not get any error message, but I do not get any result either. The very same happends when I try to connect to the server with tsql - the last line in the console which never changes is `Setting reestr as default database in login packet ...`.

Comment: Probably, I need some extra manipulation in SQL Server Configuration Manager. What I have know is 1) Named Pipes and TCP/IP enabled 2) SQL Server, SQL Server Agent and SQL Server browser running. Probably there should be some additional IP and ports tuning. I do not know.

Comment: Well, I did some manipulations on IP addresses tab in SQL Server Configuration Manager and now it works. Thank you for help!

Comment: @Jacobian, glad, that I was able to help, at least a little. ) What have you changed in IP addresses tab?

Comment: @Jacobian, ah I see.

Comment: It'd be nice to see where in the SQL Configuration Manager you changed all of these values and which IP Addresses were changed