# Connect to SQL Server 2008 using python

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

I am trying to access MS SQL server from python.

I installed pymssql and this is my code

```
import pymssql

conn = pymssql.connect(host='SAM-WOLPTP\SAM', user='SAM', password='password', database='test')

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE persons(id INT, name VARCHAR(100))')
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO persons VALUES(%d, %s)", \
[ (1, 'John Doe'), (2, 'Jane Doe') ])
conn.commit()  # you must call commit() to persist your data if you don't set autocommit to True

conn.close()
```

While running the program I am getting this error:

> pymssql.InterfaceError: Connection to the database failed for unknown reason

Comment: Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150524/unable-to-connect-to-sql-server-via-pymssql

Comment: Thanks.. i tried that.. I believe it is a version problem. My SQL server is 64 bit but for pymssql 64 bit is not getting installed i tried with 32 bit its getting installed.